# Wrong classes generated for batch edit

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

Strange thing.

My Grid seems and work correct, only untypical thing is that input during editing has:

```
class="text-box single-line"
```

instead of

```
class="k-textbox k-input"
```

Also in case when grid is completly same like in demo.

I dont know how it can happens. Copy of whole view - without some js :

```
@model IEnumerable<TranslationModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Translations";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PrivateLayout.cshtml";
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
}

<h2>Translations</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TranslationModel>(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Shortcut).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(e => e.LanguageName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Content);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("ExtraPopUpEdit").Click("ExtraPopUpEdit").Text("..."); }).Width(100);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => {
            toolbar.Save();
        })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable((p => p.PageSizes(new[] { 5 , 10, 20, 50, 100 })))
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(10)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Aggregates(a =>
        {
            a.Add(e => e.Content.Equals(string.Empty)).Count();
        }
        )
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(e => e.Id);
            model.Field(e => e.Shortcut).Editable(false);
            model.Field(e => e.LanguageName).Editable(false);
        })
        .Group(g => g.Add(e => e.Shortcut))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Translations_Read", "Admin"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Translations_Update", "Admin"))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Those classes are rendered by ASP.NET MVC when Html.EditorFor is used. If you want to remove them you have to use [editor templates](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already figured this out on your own, but for future reference for anyone else, like me, who has this problem. The solution I found is - along the lines of what Atanas said - to just copy the EditorTemplates folder from Kendo's distribution into your project. They have templates for 12 different types (in both ascx and cshtml).

The directory I copied is within the Kendo download, in \wrappers\aspnetmvc\Examples\VS2013\Kendo.Mvc.Examples\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates. Copy that into your ~/Views/Shared, delete either the *.ascx or *.cshtml files depending on your needs, and you're good to go!